# Is the Orange Is The New Black lay-down alarm real?

Tags: orange-is-the-new-black

In Orange Is The New Black, there's an alarm periodically that causes inmates to lie prone on the ground. How similar is this to real correctional facilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, it is a real protocol that some facilities use, but it is used inaccurately in OITNB.  Mostly, its purpose is in open areas (outside). Most other times the call is for "Lock Down" wherein all inmates are to report to their bunk/cell areas.

The some of the main purposes of getting all inmates down on the ground (in a hurry) are to:

1. Quickly diffuse a situation.
2. Find out who is the aggressor/victim in a crowded area (as all innocent parties will disperse and flatten, when aggressors usually continue aggressing)
3. Thwarting escape attempts (Those that do not flatten are at risk of getting shot in maximum security institutions when the alarm/call is given)